# Update inside a loop

Tags: apex

I need help to remove the update from the loop, my code:

```
            for (Establishment__c ests: [SELECT Id, Cobro_Anticipado__c, EstablishmentCode__c
                    FROM Establishment__c
                    WHERE EstablishmentCode__c IN: establishmentCodesEnabled and Account__c =: idAccount]) 
                {
                if (ests != null) {
                        ests.Codigo_de_Tasa__c = '67';
                        if (ests.Cobro_Anticipado__c != true) {
                            ests.Cobro_Anticipado__c = true;
                            ests.Alta_Baja_CobroAnticipado__c = system.today();
                        }
                        update ests;
                    }
                    hasNoError = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the common uses for [collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm), like a `List`

```java
// declare something that can hold multiple things
List<My_SObject__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<My_SObject__c>();

for(My_SObject__c myRec :<query or other iterable here>){
    // do your work, and add the record to the collection
    myRec.My_Field__c = 'value';
    recordsToUpdate.add(myRec);
}

// DML outside of the loop
update recordsToUpdate;
```